# How to disable the extension of brush in d3

Tags: d3.js

For the brush in d3, how to let its length be fixed? What I want to do is that users can change the position of the brush but can not change the size of the brush.

I use

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(xOverview)
  .extent([0, 1/10])
  .on("brush", brushed);
```

but how about `brushed()`?

Comment: what does your 'brushed' function look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example built on [Bostock's Focus+Context](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367):

```
// get brush
var b = context
  .select('.brush');
// remove ability to resize it
b.selectAll('.resize')
  .remove();
// remove ability to select from background
b.select('.background')
  .remove();
// set it to a size
brush.extent([new Date(2000, 0, 1),new Date(2001, 0, 1)])
// draw it
brush(b);
// fire redraw event
brush.event(b);
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .area {
    fill: steelblue;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .brush .extent {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .125;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 100,
        left: 40
      },
      margin2 = {
        top: 430,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
      x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
      y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
      y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
      xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
      yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x2)
      .on("brush", brushed);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("monotone")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y0(height)
      .y1(function(d) {
        return y(d.price);
      });

    var area2 = d3.svg.area()
      .interpolate("monotone")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x2(d.date);
      })
      .y0(height2)
      .y1(function(d) {
        return y2(d.price);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var focus = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "focus")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "context")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

    var data = '[{"date":"Jan 2000","price":"1394.46"},{"date":"Feb 2000","price":"1366.42"},{"date":"Mar 2000","price":"1498.58"},{"date":"Apr 2000","price":"1452.43"},{"date":"May 2000","price":"1420.6"},{"date":"Jun 2000","price":"1454.6"},{"date":"Jul 2000","price":"1430.83"},{"date":"Aug 2000","price":"1517.68"},{"date":"Sep 2000","price":"1436.51"},{"date":"Oct 2000","price":"1429.4"},{"date":"Nov 2000","price":"1314.95"},{"date":"Dec 2000","price":"1320.28"},{"date":"Jan 2001","price":"1366.01"},{"date":"Feb 2001","price":"1239.94"},{"date":"Mar 2001","price":"1160.33"},{"date":"Apr 2001","price":"1249.46"},{"date":"May 2001","price":"1255.82"},{"date":"Jun 2001","price":"1224.38"},{"date":"Jul 2001","price":"1211.23"},{"date":"Aug 2001","price":"1133.58"},{"date":"Sep 2001","price":"1040.94"},{"date":"Oct 2001","price":"1059.78"},{"date":"Nov 2001","price":"1139.45"},{"date":"Dec 2001","price":"1148.08"},{"date":"Jan 2002","price":"1130.2"},{"date":"Feb 2002","price":"1106.73"},{"date":"Mar 2002","price":"1147.39"},{"date":"Apr 2002","price":"1076.92"},{"date":"May 2002","price":"1067.14"},{"date":"Jun 2002","price":"989.82"},{"date":"Jul 2002","price":"911.62"},{"date":"Aug 2002","price":"916.07"},{"date":"Sep 2002","price":"815.28"},{"date":"Oct 2002","price":"885.76"},{"date":"Nov 2002","price":"936.31"},{"date":"Dec 2002","price":"879.82"},{"date":"Jan 2003","price":"855.7"},{"date":"Feb 2003","price":"841.15"},{"date":"Mar 2003","price":"848.18"},{"date":"Apr 2003","price":"916.92"},{"date":"May 2003","price":"963.59"},{"date":"Jun 2003","price":"974.5"},{"date":"Jul 2003","price":"990.31"},{"date":"Aug 2003","price":"1008.01"},{"date":"Sep 2003","price":"995.97"},{"date":"Oct 2003","price":"1050.71"},{"date":"Nov 2003","price":"1058.2"},{"date":"Dec 2003","price":"1111.92"},{"date":"Jan 2004","price":"1131.13"},{"date":"Feb 2004","price":"1144.94"},{"date":"Mar 2004","price":"1126.21"},{"date":"Apr 2004","price":"1107.3"},{"date":"May 2004","price":"1120.68"},{"date":"Jun 2004","price":"1140.84"},{"date":"Jul 2004","price":"1101.72"},{"date":"Aug 2004","price":"1104.24"},{"date":"Sep 2004","price":"1114.58"},{"date":"Oct 2004","price":"1130.2"},{"date":"Nov 2004","price":"1173.82"},{"date":"Dec 2004","price":"1211.92"},{"date":"Jan 2005","price":"1181.27"},{"date":"Feb 2005","price":"1203.6"},{"date":"Mar 2005","price":"1180.59"},{"date":"Apr 2005","price":"1156.85"},{"date":"May 2005","price":"1191.5"},{"date":"Jun 2005","price":"1191.33"},{"date":"Jul 2005","price":"1234.18"},{"date":"Aug 2005","price":"1220.33"},{"date":"Sep 2005","price":"1228.81"},{"date":"Oct 2005","price":"1207.01"},{"date":"Nov 2005","price":"1249.48"},{"date":"Dec 2005","price":"1248.29"},{"date":"Jan 2006","price":"1280.08"},{"date":"Feb 2006","price":"1280.66"},{"date":"Mar 2006","price":"1294.87"},{"date":"Apr 2006","price":"1310.61"},{"date":"May 2006","price":"1270.09"},{"date":"Jun 2006","price":"1270.2"},{"date":"Jul 2006","price":"1276.66"},{"date":"Aug 2006","price":"1303.82"},{"date":"Sep 2006","price":"1335.85"},{"date":"Oct 2006","price":"1377.94"},{"date":"Nov 2006","price":"1400.63"},{"date":"Dec 2006","price":"1418.3"},{"date":"Jan 2007","price":"1438.24"},{"date":"Feb 2007","price":"1406.82"},{"date":"Mar 2007","price":"1420.86"},{"date":"Apr 2007","price":"1482.37"},{"date":"May 2007","price":"1530.62"},{"date":"Jun 2007","price":"1503.35"},{"date":"Jul 2007","price":"1455.27"},{"date":"Aug 2007","price":"1473.99"},{"date":"Sep 2007","price":"1526.75"},{"date":"Oct 2007","price":"1549.38"},{"date":"Nov 2007","price":"1481.14"},{"date":"Dec 2007","price":"1468.36"},{"date":"Jan 2008","price":"1378.55"},{"date":"Feb 2008","price":"1330.63"},{"date":"Mar 2008","price":"1322.7"},{"date":"Apr 2008","price":"1385.59"},{"date":"May 2008","price":"1400.38"},{"date":"Jun 2008","price":"1280"},{"date":"Jul 2008","price":"1267.38"},{"date":"Aug 2008","price":"1282.83"},{"date":"Sep 2008","price":"1166.36"},{"date":"Oct 2008","price":"968.75"},{"date":"Nov 2008","price":"896.24"},{"date":"Dec 2008","price":"903.25"},{"date":"Jan 2009","price":"825.88"},{"date":"Feb 2009","price":"735.09"},{"date":"Mar 2009","price":"797.87"},{"date":"Apr 2009","price":"872.81"},{"date":"May 2009","price":"919.14"},{"date":"Jun 2009","price":"919.32"},{"date":"Jul 2009","price":"987.48"},{"date":"Aug 2009","price":"1020.62"},{"date":"Sep 2009","price":"1057.08"},{"date":"Oct 2009","price":"1036.19"},{"date":"Nov 2009","price":"1095.63"},{"date":"Dec 2009","price":"1115.1"},{"date":"Jan 2010","price":"1073.87"},{"date":"Feb 2010","price":"1104.49"},{"date":"Mar 2010","price":"1140.45"}]';
    
    data = JSON.parse(data).map(type);
  
    x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    })));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.price;
    }))]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

    focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

    context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2);

    context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
      .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
    
    var b = context
      .select('.brush');
    b.selectAll('.resize')
      .remove();
    b.select('.background')
      .remove();
    brush.extent([new Date(2000, 0, 1),new Date(2001, 0, 1)])
    brush(b);
    brush.event(b);

    function brushed() {
      x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }

    function type(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.price = +d.price;
      return d;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!